# Preventing spam sent using my SE profile

Tags: support, abuse

I was spammed by this today:

> “Hi? Greeting,
>   I have read your profile some minutes ago ? english.stackexchange.com 
>    & I think you are a nice person? I'd like to get to know you better.for a chance to discuss an important issue? & we can share great experiences together, I'm sorry if i am embarrassing you i don,t mean so i think you are a nice person & there is something important i want to share with you, Therefore we request you to kindly contact us to E-mail address (  Vivianaisatou@gmx.com  ) not in this site because i am a new in this community and i don't visit this site often,
>
> I am very curious to know more about you,please e-mail me i await your response. Best regards,

I do write my email at my profile, which help other users communicate with me.

Is there any way the community / SE management can help eliminate data mining the users' details by spammers, while still letting us put our emails in public?

Comment: Sure you had to quote the spam in its entirety, including the email?

Comment: What about those who look at your profile and email from there, without scraping? Do you want SE to filter those for you as well?

Comment: Why not just not write out your email, and give it to users on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: Alternatively, write it out in a human friendly way that isn't as friendly to scraping/regex (such as: `my.email [at] example.com`) - I do that myself, and don't get spammed.

Comment: See my profile for example - just put your email as image.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't see what they can do. Your profile is free text and trying to automatically find e-mail addresses in it will go wrong.

The fact that your e-mail is public means that it ***will*** be obtained by spammers at some point. You can't stop "bad" people contacting you if you've made your e-mail address public so "good" people can.

The only way to prevent this is to **not** put your e-mail in your public profile.